How to tell the LLVM interpreter (`lli`) where the missing symbols are as I do when linking?
I have exported Rust code to a LLVM-IR (.ll) file and was able to compile and link it manually using both, clang and llc + link.exe. It required to link against a lot of system libraries, Rust libraries and a temporary generated .o file from Rust. I am developing on Windows.
My goal is to run the .ll file using lli. For this I have to tell lli where to find the missing symbols. I couldn't get the solution from this question to work. I tried -load and -extra-archive + -extra-object. Sadly, there is no output, not even if the sources where found.
For clang it was necessary to add 3 types of sources:

Rust libraries, e.g.:
C:\Users\$USER_NAME\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\libstd-$RANDOM_STRING.rlib


System libraries, e.g.:
-lws2_32


And a temporary file generated by running cargo rustc --release -- -C save-temps:
.\target\release\deps\$PROJECT_NAME.$RANDOM_STRING.rcgu.o



How do I pass these files to lli correctly?
Context
My goal is to debug the Rust generated LLVM-IR. I found this answer but found this tool to be more promising. However, it requires lli as far as I can tell.
Update
The correct way of linking is before passing the .ll file. This way lli is complaining about wrong paths, etc. Libraries are passed with:

Rust libraries, e.g.:
--extra-archive="C:\Users\$USER_NAME\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\libstd-$RANDOM_STRING.rlib"


And a temporary .o file:
--extra-object=".\target\release\deps\$PROJECT_NAME.$RANDOM_STRING.rcgu.o"


System libraries .lib would be:
--extra-archive="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\msvcrt.lib"



However, 'lli' is still complaining about not found symbols which are in ws2_32.lib and userenv.lib. For some reason it cannot load them from the static library, but clang can when building? Adding windows libraries dynamically fixed it:
--load="C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll"

Yet, there is another error:
LLVM ERROR: Could not resolve external global address: __rust_no_alloc_shim_is_unstable

The allocator shim was supposed to be added with the temporary file. And I assume it is this way when building with clang.
